# VueConstructor type is missing from Vue3 compat build?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

We are in the process of migrating a Vue 2 app with TypeScript to Vue 3. Since that App is rather big, we need to use `@vue/compat` in order to be able to migrate our App one step at a time.

However, when closely trying to follow the [official migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html), we are running into problems around using the type `VueConstructor`:

```
 error  in src/presentation/App.vue:43:25

TS2614: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'VueConstructor'. Did you mean to use 'import VueConstructor from "vue"' instead?
    41 |
    42 | <script lang="ts">
  > 43 | import Vue, { PropType, VueConstructor } from 'vue';
       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    44 | import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
    45 | import WarningAnonymousEdit from '@/presentation/components/WarningAnonymousEdit.vue';
    46 | import Events from '@/events';
```

It is used in the following way in a Vue2 app:

```
export default ( Vue as VueConstructor<Vue & InstanceType<typeof StateMixin>> ).extend( {
    mixins: [ StateMixin ],
    name: 'App',
    computed: {
        isSaving(): boolean {
            // methods on ExampleMixin are now known to TypeScript as existing on `this`
            return this.isMethodOnMixin();
        },
    },
    // [...]
} );
```

The above code works just fine with Vue 2 and allows TypeScript to know that the methods on `StateMixin` are also available on the class.

Any suggestions for how to make it work with the Vue3 migration build?

PS: Issue [#4330](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4330) is related but not really helpful

PPS: This question used to also ask about `PropType` not being exported by `'vue'`, but that was resolved by upgrading to TypeScript 4.

Comment: Any updates on this? How did you end up resolving?

Comment: @Marlo I don't fully remember, but if I now look at the file, it has: `import { PropType, defineComponent } from 'vue';` and `export default defineComponent( {` (Though that's the final state, no `@vue/compat` involved anymore.)